# Layover in Korea

Tags: international-travel, south-korea, korean-air

Hello I am traveling back to the Philippines which is my home country and I have a layover in Korea for almost 20hrs do I need a visa to explore Seoul? By the way I do have a Japanese visa is it possible for me to explore Seoul without visa?